# Is there a way to serialize a C++ class without the use of a library?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, serialization, tcp

I will attempt to keep it short and specific. I am working on a project that copies a file, and then creates an exact copy of it. I would like to improve this project so that it copies a file on a server, and sends this data to a client, which then recreates the file on the local machine. I have my client/server set up using Winsock, and I am able to send a char* between the two using a TCP socket. My problem is... fitting all of this class data into a char*. I assume that serialization is the best way to do this, however, I want to keep the code as simple as possible and, if possible, would very much like to eliminate the use of libraries for this particular project.

Here is my code for actually saving the file:
h:

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SaveFile{
private:
   streampos fileSize;//streampos data type holds current position of the buffer pointer or file pointer
   char* memBlock;
   string fileName;
public:
   SaveFile();
   ~SaveFile();

   streampos getSize();
   char* getMemBlock();

};
```

cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SaveFile.h"

SaveFile::SaveFile(){//default constructor
   cout << "Please enter file directory: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   //ios::ate means that the get pointer will be positioned at end of the file
   ifstream file(fileName, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

   if (file.is_open()){
         fileSize = file.tellg();//because get pointer is at end of file, tellg will return size of file in question
         memBlock = new char[fileSize];//allocating memory for the file

         file.seekg(0, ios::beg);//return get position to beginning of file
         file.read(memBlock, fileSize);//read file into memBlock variable
         file.close();//close file

         //default destructor will take care of cleanup
   }

}

SaveFile::~SaveFile(){}//default destructor

streampos SaveFile::getSize(){
   return fileSize;
}

char* SaveFile::getMemBlock(){
   return memBlock;
}
```

Here is the code to reconstruct the file:
h:

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SaveFile{
private:
   streampos fileSize;//streampos data type holds current position of the buffer pointer or file pointer
   char* memBlock;
   string fileName;
public:
   SaveFile();
   ~SaveFile();

   streampos getSize();
   char* getMemBlock();

};
```

cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WriteFile.h"

WriteFile::WriteFile(SaveFile sf){
   cout << "Please enter new file name: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   ofstream file(fileName, ios::out|ios::binary);
   file.write(sf.getMemBlock(), sf.getSize());
   file.close();
}

WriteFile::~WriteFile(){}
```

An example of this code in action would be:

```
#include "SaveFile.h"
#include "WriteFile.h"

int main(){
    SaveFile s;
    WriteFile w(s);
}
```

So my goal here is somehow saving the contents of the SaveFile class to a char*, and then transferring that through a TCP socket to another machine, which then converts that char* back to a SaveFile object, and passes it to WriteFile so that it can recreate the file in question.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the data members of `SaveFile`?

Comment: `SaveFile` and `WriteFile` are more like function names, as opposed to class names! Smells like a bad design of classes!

Comment: Ah sorry, I will include the SaveFile.h file in a moment.

Comment: @Nawaz When constructors are doing anything other than initializing members, you know there's code smell.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a first draft. I'm trying to figure out how to bring it all together.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've added the .h files which contain all data members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build your own serialization process.

First, understand that there may be padding between the fields of your class or structure.  You may not want to write the structure contents as-is.  For example, you may want to pack the data into a buffer.

Secondly, variable length fields need to be treated differently.  Pointers to character arrays are an example.  Usually the length is written followed by the content.

Non-POD types cannot be directly written or read.  For example, the `std::string` class.  The string class has some member data, but commonly, the string content is elsewhere (like in dynamic memory).

I recommend implement the following methods for each object:

- Size of bytes in a buffer -- Returns the number of bytes in a buffer
  that this object occupies.
- Load from buffer -- Loads its contents from a pointer to a buffer and
  increments the pointer by the size.
- Write to buffer -- stores its contents to a buffer via a pointer and
  updates the pointer.

The process:

1. determine the size of bytes in the buffer for the object
2. allocate the buffer
3. write the buffer using the "Write to buffer" method
4. block write the buffer to a file or device.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: In this case, would it be viable for me to simply isolate each data variable that I need in order to recreate the file, convert it to a char*, send it, and then convert it back to its original data type on the client side? Or is such an approach bound to create errors?

Comment: In most data transmissions, when writing, the essential data is copied into a buffer (packet), then a checksum is applied and the packet sent.  On the receiving side, the checksum is verified, then the data is copied from the buffer into structure members.  The above scheme follows the idea of "the data member knows best how to write its content into a buffer".  Similarly with reading.  This allows objects to change with minimal disruption to the communication process.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will attempt to take your approach!